# User Validation for Desktop Applications?

Tags: php, api, desktop

I have written an API for my latest project. Written entirely in PHP, it currently supports web and mobile applications. We would like to expand that to desktop applications as well, but I'm not exactly sure how to enable to user to login through the desktop application, while still protecting the username and password from said application.

There are many brilliant developers on Stackoverflow, so shoot me some brilliant answers!

Comment: Are you asking about storing passwords in a local database for this desktop application?

Comment: For clarity - are you asking how to allow applications that you write (and distribute to end users) access to your web service while blocking third party applications?

Comment: Mike, nope. The application will be developed by 3rd parties, so I want to ensure they aren't able to store usernames and passwords. Quentin, I wish they were all written by us, it would be so much easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The application will be developed by 3rd parties, so I want to ensure they aren't able to store usernames and passwords

If the application has to send usernames and passwords, then it has to be able to have access to them, so don't use them inside the application at all.

Use [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth). This is the solution used by quite a lot of large organisations, [including Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/faq).

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. What comes to mind:

- Issue a [Certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate) signed by your [CA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority) and verify later, eg via the [OpenSSL lib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) or [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol).
- Use [Public key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) encryption, eg via [GnuPG lib](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gnupg.php), and grant access only to known pub keys.
- Use any kind of [Token based authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_token) or any other [two factor authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-factor_authentication)..
- Just give them another set of API credentials (Secret Key, API Key)

Comment: The developer of the API will have API credentials. I just need the site users to be able to login through the app.

Answer (score 0):

its a desktop application, it has full access to the users keyboard and memory. if the application should have a login form where end users type in their usernames and passwords, the application has this data by definition.

the only solution would be to distribute the login-application yourself which does some sort of toked based authentication and provide the 3rd party applications a login token via your api.

oauth and other singe-sign-on systems on the web usually use an iframe or popup which comes from the system-to-login-to itself. no 3rd party website or application should be allowed to provide this input fields.